# RTK: useSelector() vs store.getState()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux-toolkit

I am working on a project with another developer and we're at an impasse on how the authentication flow should go. We use RTK for state management. In the `EntryPoint.tsx`, here's my approach:

```
export default function EntryPoint({ layoutHandler }: EntryPointProps) {

  const { isDarkMode, themeColors } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { accessToken } = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.auth)

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar
        animated
        backgroundColor={themeColors['neutral-00']}
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
      />

      <View
        onLayout={layoutHandler}
        style={[
          globalStyles.container,
          {
            backgroundColor: themeColors['neutral-00'],
            paddingBottom:
              Platform.OS === 'android' ? styleGuide.layout.spacing.md : 0,
          },
        ]}
      >
        {!accessToken ? <AuthNavigator /> : <MainNavigator />}
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

In this approach, during logout, all that's needed is to remove/destroy accessToken and you'll be sent to the navigator stack that contains screens for authentication (OnBoarding, Login, Verify Login)

Here's my colleague's approach

```
export default function EntryPoint({ layoutHandler }: EntryPointProps) {
  const { isDarkMode, themeColors } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const authState = store.getState().auth as AuthStateType;
  const { isOnboarded } = authState;

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar
        animated
        backgroundColor={themeColors['neutral-00']}
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
      />

      <View
        onLayout={layoutHandler}
        style={[
          globalStyles.container,
          {
            backgroundColor: themeColors['neutral-00'],
            paddingBottom:
              Platform.OS === 'android' ? styleGuide.layout.spacing.md : 0,
          },
        ]}
      >
        {!isOnboarded ? <OnboardingNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Basically, he's now rearranged the navigator stacks such that `OnBoardingNavigator` stack contains only Login & AuthNavigator stack. Do note that the `AuthNavigator` now contains Login screen again and the the MainNavigator. Logout now works in such a way that after accessToken is removed, we navigate back to Login screen.

Reason for his approach is he doesn't want to use `useSelector` as subscribing to the store is costly and will lead to unknowns and unpredictability.

I seriously disagree with this as I believe the cost of subscription isn't worth refactoring all the navigation stacks which now mixes multiple screens in stacks they do not belong in.  Simply using `useSelector` will make the app React . However, He says reactivity comes at a cost.

What is the best approach/practice in this case?

Comment: `Reason for his approach is he doesn't want to use useSelector as subscribing to the store is costly and will lead to unknowns and unpredictability.` I don't understand his argument. Assuming you use a good selector (one that doesn't change value often), the subscription is low cost. And what unknowns and unpredictability is he referring to?

Comment: "subscribing to the store is costly and will lead to unknowns and unpredictability" - Says who, other than your colleague? Selecting state in the `useSelector` hook is a known and predictable entity. The argument is senseless. Inform your colleague that `const authState = store.getState().auth as AuthStateType;` *could* be considered an unintentional side-effect and that they should use either the `useSelector` hook or a `useEffect` hook with a `store.subscribe` callback so the component is correctly subscribed to state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux maintainer here.
Please don't use `store.getState()` in your component like that ever.

If your store changes in the background, the component will not rerender with a new value. If you write your selector correctly, it will only rerender when the selector value changes.

So you can optimize here, but should keep the `useSelector` call.

```js
const isOnboarded = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.auth.accessToken.isOnboarded)
```

is a lot better.

Comment: **TLDR; don't destructure your returned value.** It's worth noting the @phry is returning a non-destructured variable vs the OP's destructured `accessToken`. Since `useSelector` uses a strict reference equality check, returning a destructured value will cause your component to rerender on any change to the store. However `const accessToken  = useSelector((state:RootState) => state.auth.accessToken)` will only re-render on changes to `accessToken`.